# C# code to print pdf file from crystal report and also set custom scale ratio

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, scale

I want to print my report to 66% custom scale ratio programitically, but i am not able to do it.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;

public void PrintPdfFile(string pdfFilePath, int scaleRatio)
{
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
    report.Load(pdfFilePath);

    PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    printerSettings.PrinterName = "Your Printer Name";
    printerSettings.Copies = 1;
    printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
    printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    PageSettings pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings);
    pageSettings.Landscape = false;

    report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerSettings.PrinterName;
    report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);

    report.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to scale a pdf file for printing but what you are doing seems strange.

Crystal Reports can load a Crystal Report files (.rpt files) -- Not pdf (.pdf files).

Can you clarify the general logic of what you are trying to do and why Crystal Reports is part of the process.

Comment: I am just going to produce pdf form crystal report but i also want to set scalling ratio.

Comment: In that case, Crystal Reports is not relevant.  Just pursue a solution that deals with the pdf file and keep the Crystal runtime out of the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are really after is fitting the pdf export printout to the printer page size, there is at least one 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation/scheduling tool that provides that functionality.

Ken Hamady maintains a list of such 3rd-party tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).